# Nodejs - How to get the version of a dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is there a way to get the version of an external dependency in JS code, without hardcoding it?

Comment: within your code or by using the CLI?

Comment: within the JS code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to get the value of express you could do something like the following. You are looping over each folder in the node modules and adding the name and the version to an object.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const dirs = fs.readdirSync('node_modules');
const packages = {};

dirs.forEach(function(dir) {
   const file = 'node_modules/' + dir + '/package.json';
   const json = require(file);
   const name = json.name;
   const version = json.version;
   packages[name] = name;
   packages[version] = version;
});

console.log(packages['react-native']); // will log the version
```

Comment: is this guaranteed in production? my real application is in React Native, will it break there?

Comment: moreover, is there an easy npm package to do this for me?

Comment: this will have to be done on the server, it shouldn't break anything. I don't think you need an npm package, you can just use this short snippet.