# Programmatically get version of npm dependency at build time

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

Let's say I've installed formik into my node application, so my `package.json` includes it:

```
...
dependencies: {
  ...
  "formik": "^2.4.1",
}
```

I want to programmatically get the version in `script.js` on build time. How can I do that?

Per this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116754/nodejs-how-to-get-the-version-of-a-dependency), I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
const json = require("node_modules/formik/package.json");
const version = json.version;
```

First line raises the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'node_modules/simple-icons/package.json'